# Use of underscore in interger values or Number values in Tensorflow documentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

if we check below documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval it uses underscore (_) in the integer values like for batch size . What does this underscore signifies is it same as decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscores are for improved readability, but do not have any deeper meaning. See [this](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/21/whats-new-in-python-3-6/pep-515-underscores-in-numeric-literals#:%7E:text=PEP%20515%3A%20Underscores%20in%20Numeric%20Literals,-PEP%20515%20adds&text=Single%20underscores%20are%20allowed%20between,a%20row%20are%20not%20allowed.&text=PEP%20written%20by%20Georg%20Brandl%20and%20Serhiy%20Storchaka.) for more information. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow

ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.random(seed=4).take(2_000)
print(len(list(ds1.map(lambda x: x))))
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.random(seed=4).take(200_000)
print(len(list(ds1.map(lambda x: x))))
```

```
2000
200000
```

Comment: Yes Thank you this was very useful